# Finding the local name of a module from within that module

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I'm trying to get the exact module name that a module was imported with, from inside that module.  Something like this:

```
def install():
    print 'Local module name is %s' % __localModuleName__
```

And when I ran:

```
import myModule as mm
mm.install()
```

It would print

```
Local module name is mm
```

The script I'm trying to make installs itself into the external application Maya.  Maya evaluates the string I pass it on demand in python.  Right now, I'm trying to give Maya the string `"myModule.run()"`.  In this case, I have to know the exact name of `myModule` when `myModule.install()` is first run. `__name__` isn't specific enough if the user imports the module using `import myModule as otherModule`.

If there's a better way to do this that doesn't involve using the exact module name, I'd love to know.  Like somehow converting a reference of `myModule.run` into a string I could store in Maya and later unpack.  I've been trying to use the `inspect` module to find this information, but I keep finding situations where it doesn't work and I have to go back and fiddle with it some more.  It also seems kind of messy.  This is what I'm using right now, which doesn't work if `myModule` is called from `__main__`.

```
MODULENAME = None
fr = inspect.currentframe()
try:
    while fr and not MODULENAME:
        if fr.f_globals:
            for name, obj in fr.f_globals.iteritems():
                if hasattr(obj, '__file__') and inspect.ismodule(obj) and obj.__file__ == __file__:
                    MODULENAME = name
        fr = fr.f_back
except:
    pass
finally:
    del fr
```

If there is no good solution, I plan to remove the above and tell the users that my module can't be imported using `import myModule as ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach close to the one you are trying should work - bt it would be convolutd as you could verify.

Moreover, the "import module as othername" syntax is just a conveninet way of biinding the module object to another variable.

It is just the equivalent of

```
import module
othername = module
del module
```

And your code should not depend on this for running.
However, in the global `sys.modules` dictionary, your module always shows up with its "real" name.  Therefore, if you can pass an expression in a string to the host application, you should try to access your module within that dictionary - much less convoluted.

Instead of passing:
`guessedname.run()`

try passing:

```
__import__("sys").modules["<module_name>"].run()
```

And care not about the variable name that references your module in the running code. (this will even allow the user to do `from module import *` for your code.

Comment: Thanks, that is a far better solution than using frames!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this can ever work is like this:

```
import some.plugin as wanna_have

wanna_have.install(globals(), "wanna_have")
```

Why is that? You need *both* the namespace of the importing module and the imported module here, and the first requires you to pass globals(). The only way to prevent that is to go *up* one stackframe in the install() method, assuming the calling code is what has the aliased name. When you use the signature `install(importer=None, imported=__name__)` the need to pass all that stuff can be reduced to the cases when "as" is used, or the caller is not one frame up.

Comment: It is not 
"the_only_ way this can _ever_ work" - python has enough introspection to allow somewthing along the lines the OP is asking. But requiring an explicit init call in this case is very clean, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution:

```
print 'Local module name is %s'%[key for key in vars() if 'myModule' in str(vars()[key])][0]
```

[0] - this is just in case your module was imported several times under different names and you just pick up the first one. If your module wasn't imported, you get the "IndexError: list index out of range" which I suppose you can handle by yourself.

I tried it with

```
import numpy as np
```

Then I applied the oneliner I mentioned above:

```
print 'Local module name is %s',[key for key in vars() if 'numpy' in str(vars()[key])][0]
```

and get as result:

```
Local module name is np
```

Comment: tis won't help - he does not have to find the module name in the module running his code - he has to find its name in a module written by a third person who is importing his module